# How do get valiable in html via jquery code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**I Edited**

I have a html

```
<select name="action-grid">
    <option  selected > Select</option>
    <option  value="1" >Edit</option>
</select>   
<select  name="action-grid">
   <option  selected > Select</option>
   <option  value="2" >Edit</option>
 </select>
<?php $_product = $this->getProductBy($values);?>
<div><?php echo $_product->getName();?></div>
```

in code php. i have function getProductBy($value){....}. in view i have grid product, in column action i want when chose option edit value will set variable $value.

Comment: You can't set javascript variable value to PHP variable on the same page you need to do ajax call if you want to set PHP variable value.

Comment: Could you please brief what exactly you want to do with that php variable?

Comment: You cannot pass variable values from the current page javascript to the current page PHP code... PHP code runs at the server side and it doesn't know anything about what is going on on the client side.

You need to pass variables to PHP code from html-form using another mechanism, such as submitting form on GET or POST methods or if you do not want to reload the page then using AJAX

Comment: in code php. i have function getProductEdit($value){....}. in view. i have grid product. in column action.  I want when click edit value  product_id of product will set variable $value.

Comment: Could you please mention this in the post instead in comments?

Answer (score 2):

Html code, (Assuming Jquery included)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function getNewFunction(val) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "./myPhp.php",
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        'value': val
    },
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }
  });
 }
</script>    
<select onchange="getNewFunction(this.value)" name="action-grid">
 <option  selected > Select</option>
 <option  value="1" >First</option>
</select>
```

myPhp.php

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['value'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per you mentioned in comments

Your script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function getNewFunction(gridValue){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url : 'some_file.php',
            data: {value: gridValue},
            success: function(response) {}
        })
    }
</script>
```

in some_file.php file

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['value'];

//your funtion here
function getProductEdit($value)
{
    .....
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="getNewFunction($('option:selected', this))" name="action-grid">
    <option selected>Select</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getNewFunction(value) {
        alert(value.text());
    }
</script>
```

try this way

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1cnw8t3j/)